# Не устанавливается модуль Pygame. Ошибка в консоли

Tags: python

Ошибка:

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

[image: Сам Python в Path добавлен]

Comment: Прошу прощения. Сглупил. В консоли вводил python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user. @Эникейщик

Comment: А если просто python, а не python3?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\юрий\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (2.0.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Юрий\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command. В самом компиляторе пишет, что библиотеки pygame не существует @Эникейщик

Comment: А другой питон случайно не установлен?

Comment: @Эникейщик нет, второй питон не установлен. Только что, накатил свежую винду. Ошибка осталась:D Среда разработки PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена. Для того, чтобы корректно установить модуль на новых версиях Windows, необходимо удалить старый Python.exe и установить его из Microsoft Store.